# How best to remove mailbox accounts from the organisation chart

Tags: active-directory

We are currently looking at using the organisation chart in SharePoint 2013 and have noticed that there are many mailbox and service accounts showing under people. I can think of a few ways around this, but in the process of searching on the internet I can find nothing about this issue. I appreciate that this will depend on how you have Active Directory set up, but I am sure we are not the only one. How have other people addressed this?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to have them in an OU that is excluded from the user profile import.